# Mounting a Windows hidden share in /etc/fstab. How do I escape the $

Tags: bash, ubuntu, cifs

If I want to mount a Windows hidden share to my Ubuntu filesystem, I do this and it works just fine:

```
mount –t cifs –o username=root,password=rootpassword,uid=www-data,gid=www-data //domain/dir\$ /mnt/dir
```

But when I try to make an entry into /etc/fstab, escaping the "$" doesn't work:

```
//domain/dir\$ /mnt/dir cifs credientials=/path/to/credentials,uid=www-data,gid=www-data
```

My syntax should be otherwise correct as I'm able to mount using fstab other non-hidden Windows directories from the same server.

How do I escape that "$" in fstab?

Comment: What error are you getting? It's not the typo in 'credientials', is it?

Comment: mountall: mount /mnt/dir [6300] Terminated with status 32 

The credentials, spelling, everything is identical to the non-hidden shares (shares that don't include a $ in the name) that worked fine.  Only the two hidden ones failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it turns out you simply don't have to escape the $ in /etc/fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Try octal escaping:  "\044"

```
//domain/dir\044 /mnt/dir ...
```